# SpringBatch Processor: What Object in this case?

Tags: spring-batch

I have an input database MyInputEntity, lets say:

```
id, name, someCode
1,john,code_abc
2,jack,code_xyz
```

this file is processed by a spring batch job, every line it creates a line in those 2 tables:

```
OutPerson:
id
name

OutCode:
code
```

The configuration is:

```
@Bean
public Step step3_readDBWriteDB(OutCodeRepository outCodeRepository) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step3_readDBWriteDB")
            .<MyInputEntity, OutPerson>chunk(100)
            .reader(myReader())
            .processor(new MyItemProcessor(outCodeRepository))
            .writer(myWriter()).build();
}
```

The itemProcessor is like this:

```
@Override
 public OutPerson process(MyInputEntity myInput) {       
        // creation of Person
        OutPerson outPerson = MyMapper.convert(myInput);

        // Create and save outCode
        OutCode outCode = new outCode(myInput.getCode());
        OutCodeRepository.save(outCode)

        return outPerson;
    }
```

The problem here, is that Person is processed with chunk of 100. So the code is save on everyline, and person every 100 lines.

I think there is something wrong, and it should be done differently, but I dont know how ? Should I create another processor for 'Code' ? What would be the best practice in this case (for everyline, create in multi table) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to create a wrapper class called for instance `MyOutputEntity` that encapsulates `OutPerson` and `OutCode`. This class will be the output of the processor and the input of the writer. The writer will insert both persons and codes together in the same transaction (so your data is consistent in case of failure). For example:

```
class MyOutputEntity {
   private OutPerson outPerson;
   private OutCode outCode;
   // getters and setters
}

public ItemProcessor<MyInputEntity, MyOutputEntity> itemProcessor() {
    return myInputEntity -> {
        // create Person
        OutPerson outPerson = MyMapper.convert(myInputEntity);

        // Create outCode
        OutCode outCode = new outCode(myInputEntity.getCode());

        MyOutputEntity myOutputEntity = new MyOutputEntity();
        myOutputEntity.setOutPerson(outPerson);
        myOutputEntity.setOutCode(outCode);

        return myOutputEntity;
    };
}

public ItemWriter<MyOutputEntity> itemWriter() {
    return items -> {
        for (MyOutputEntity outputEntity : items) {
            outPersonRepository.save(outputEntity.getOutPerson());
            outCodeRepository.save(outputEntity.getOutCode());
        }
    };
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to keep all writing logic into writer because this is what writer for. 
I think the best would be to write both code and person together in the writer (assuming this is the same database, so they will be written in the same transaction).

But note that they will be written with chunks = `chunk(100)`

This way you could also benefit from fallback mechanism of spring batch when one write to database can fail with any error. With current situation I think you will need to resolve it by yourself.

Comment: I second this answer. I would also do the writing of both entities in the writer. I think there was a missing concept in the domain model (the encapsulation of person and code) that's why IMO the reporter tried to save the code in the processor and the person in the writer (because he/she could not return both of them from the processor and that what the encapsulation solves as shown in the example I gave). Anyway, I hope these two answers help.